# Sticking ul to bottom of a div

Tags: css

I have this div (8 of them in one page ) that have an unknown height (the height change according to the data  injection), I need to "stick" it to the bottom of the div. But it's not working out.

Css:

```
    .menuItem {
    width: 45%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    background-color: white;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    box-shadow: 0.33em 0.25em 3.25em black;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    height: 350px;
}
.menuItem h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: "Alef Hebrew", 'Lobster', cursive;
    border-bottom: solid black;
    padding-bottom: .6em;
    width: 99%;
    font-stretch: narrower;
}

.menuItem p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.menuItem span {
    font-weight: lighter;
    width: auto;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2%;
    display: table;
    margin-top: -10%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.menuItem img {
    width: 35%;
    display: table;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    box-shadow: 0.33em 0.25em 1.25em black;
    /*margin-bottom:2%;*/
}

.menuItem ul {
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: black;

    margin-top: 1em;
}

.menuItem li {
    float:left;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    direction: rtl;
    width: 33%;
    list-style: none;
}`
```

Comment: Can you create the jsfiddle example?

Comment: Yes http://jsfiddle.net/assaf/jLzza/

Comment: I think I understand your problem though a fiddle is always helpful. See my answer below and let me know in comments if it doesn't work for you. Of course, don't forget to accept the answer if it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLzza/5/ . The styles changes are annotated below.

Use the following style rules:

```
.menuItem {
  position: relative;   //New rule required for the absolute positioning of the ul.
  width: 45%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 60px;   //Pad up below as much as the height of the ul + its distance from the bottom
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0.33em 0.25em 3.25em black;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  float: left;
}

.menuItem h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: "Alef Hebrew", 'Lobster', cursive;
    border-bottom: solid black;
    padding-bottom: .6em;
    width: 99%;
    font-stretch: narrower;
}

.menuItem p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.menuItem span {
    font-weight: lighter;
    width: auto;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2%;
    display: table;
    margin-top: -10%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.menuItem img {
    width: 35%;
    display: table;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    box-shadow: 0.33em 0.25em 1.25em black;
    /*margin-bottom:2%;*/
}

.menuItem ul {
    position: absolute;  // Rule required to position it absolutely w.r.t to the div
    bottom: 10px;         // 10px of distance from the bottom.
    width: 172px;
    display: table;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: black;

    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;  // This rule is required to nullify the effect of user-agent differences
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.menuItem li {
    float:left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    direction: rtl;
    width: 50%;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: It is much better but its sliding outside the menuItem div  to the right

Comment: Oh, I saw it like that in the first fiddle. So, I thought may be you want it like that. I have updated the link to the fiddle, have a look. The latest one looks much better. I'll fix this problem also and update the link once more.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle link. Have a look and plz accept the answer by clicking on the check sign if it works for you.